# visual studio one click publish overriding LocalDatabase

Tags: c#, visual-studio, local-database, oneclick

I have a project I've been working on in C# with a local database that I want to publish.
Problem is that every time i publish a new version os the software the database get overrided and i lost all the data.
How do i set the Project so that the local database don't get overrided?

Answer (score 1):

Select the .mfd file in the Solution Explorer then go to Properties > Advanced > Copy to Output Directory and select "Copy if Newer". This will make you database to be overwritten only if you make changes to you database during development.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your local database is a file that included into your deployment package. Based on that:

**The proper way**

From version to version you may need to change database structure or extend it with new functionality. So, I suggest to exclude local database file from deployment package.
Instead of copying database file use scripts for database creation:

1. Prepare SQL scripts that create database (you probably already have them since you have database ready). Such script should create database if it's not exist, alter stored procedures, update tables if needed, etc.
2. If you have some default data, that should go with database - you can simply insert them with scripts as well. If your initial database is large and you don't want to write insert scripts - include initial database into deployment package with name that different from your active database (for example *database.initial.ext*) and rename it manually to your active database (for example *database.ext*) at application startup if such base doesn't exist.
3. At application startup run all scripts which create/update your database.
4. Continue your application execution.

As result you should have something like this (sample):

```
public static void Main(object[] args)
{
    CreateDatabaseIfNotExists();
    RunDatabaseUpdateQueries();
    InsertInitialDataIfDatabaseNew();
    // Rest of your code...
}
```

**Pros:** you will get flexible solution that could change your database when you deliver new versions.
**Cons:** you have to write update scripts and run them at application startup.

**Workaround**

As alternative for proposed flow you can simply do next:

1. Include database file into your deployment package with different name (for example *database.initial.ext*).
2. At application startup rename database file to correct one (for example *database.ext*) if it's not exist.

As result you should have something like this (sample):

```
public static void Main(object[] args)
{
    CreateDatabaseIfNotExists();
    // Rest of your code...
}
```

**Pros:** you need lest effort to implement such flow.

**Cons:** solution isn't flexible and you will face problems in case if database structure should be updated in future versions.